# how to set text in back end for inside controls in pivot uwp

Tags: c#, pivot, uwp

I am trying to set the text for the controls inside the pivot item in the following way.

```
<Pivot x:Name="galleryPivot" 
       HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}" 
       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pivotTemplate}"
       Margin="0,-10,0,10" SelectionChanged="galleryPivot_SelectionChanged">
</Pivot>

<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="pivotTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="one"></TextBlock>                                   
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

I want to set the text for the text block namely "one" in the back end.
In the c# end I am doing in the following way.

```
 PivotItem item = (sender as Pivot).ContainerFromItem((sender as Pivot).SelectedItem) as PivotItem;
 var rootGrid = item.ContentTemplate.LoadContent() as Grid;
 var tb = rootGrid.FindName("one") as TextBlock;
 tb.Text = "test";
```

I am able to get the text block controls and properties of the text block, but when I am trying to set the text in the back end I am not getting anything in the front end where as if I set the property in xaml it is working absolutely fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We don't know, where/when you are trying to set the `Text` property. This isn't nearly enough information to answer the question. Please provide a [mcve]. Note that it needs to be **minimal**, too, so strip off all unrelated XAML code as well.

Comment: We don't know, where/when you are trying to set the `Text` property.

Comment: Hi @IInspectable, var tb = rootGrid.FindName("one") as TextBlock; By this line i am getting the text block control and by tb.Text = "test"; this i am trying to set the text. Please let me know if you are able to find.

Comment: I added an answer to your other question about Data Templates. check that. Here also the same process.